# all video formats are not working in html5 video tag

Tags: html, mp4, flv, avi, video-player

I have to use any html video player in which all formats of videos play. But video tag of html5 only play mp4 and ogg. I also tried `<iframe>` tag but could not find any solution. Is there any way to handle all video formats.

Comment: To play any format video you have to use javascript plugin to do so.

Comment: Which plugin? can you please tell me that plugin name?

Comment: mentioned below  http://mediaelementjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this by using http://mediaelementjs.com/ plugin.It will play .ogv,.mp4,.webm. This will solve your problem.

Comment: I have issue with avi, flv and wmv types of video.